# If $Tx=0$ is $T$ necessarily closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, closed-graph, closed-map

Let $X, Y$ be normed spaces and $D \subseteq X$ a subspace. Let $T: X \supset D \to Y$ and $Tx=0$ for any $x$. Is $T$ closed?

I do not believe that it is closed, consider $c_{c}$ the space of sequences with finite support. $c_{c}$ is not closed in $\ell^{1}$ for example (since $c_{c}$ is dense in $\ell^{1}$) and thus we can find a sequence where $x \in \ell^{1}$ and $(x_{n})_{n} \subseteq c_{c}$ so that $x_{n} \to x$, while $Tx_{n}=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. But by defintion $x \notin \operatorname{dom}(T)$ and hence we are done?

I do not know whether I have truly understood this exercise, it seems to simple

Comment: Do you mean "closed" in the usual sense of what it means for an unbounded linear operator to be closed?  It's different than what it means to be a [closed map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps) and so I think José Carlos Santos's answer doesn't apply to your question.

Comment: Your example is fine.  You might go on and try to show that $(T,D)$ is a closed operator if and only if $D$ is a closed subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A closed map is a map which maps closed sets into closed sets. If $C\subset D$, then $T(C)=\emptyset$ (if $C=\emptyset$) or $T(C)=\{0\}$ (otherwise). In each case you get a closed set (even without assuming that $C$ is closed) and therefore, yes, $T$ is a closed map.

Besides, the graph of $T$ *is* a closed subset of $D\times Y$.

**Edit:** On the other hand, if you had in mind that $T$ may be a closed unbounded operator, then you are right. If $D$ is not a closed subset of $X$, then the graph of $T$ is not a closed subset of $X\times Y$. Therefore, in that case (as in your example), $T$ will *not* be closed.

Comment: But why does this not correspond with the theorem: $T$ is closed $\iff (x_{n})_{n} \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(T)$ with $x_{n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} x \in X$ and $Tx_{n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} y \in Y\Rightarrow x \in \operatorname{dom}(T)$  and $y = Tx$?

Comment: I don't know. I have never seen that way of describing closed maps.

Comment: I think OP means "closed" in the sense of "closed linear operator".  The operator $T$ is not closed in that sense.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. I've edited my answer. Thank you.